# Any one implementing or working on impala from cloudera?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, cloudera

Hadoop techlogies are quite confusing to me (Hbase,flume,oozie,scoop,zookeeper,Hive, hue, Bigtop,pig) and now its impala. Can someone define how exactly they are integrated ?( am a informatica developer and very little knowledge on java) atleast interms of dataware housing!

Comment: @CharlesMenguy perhaps if you really want that tag to exist, you should add it to questions that *aren't* closed as not constructive.

Comment: @Charles I don't care about the tag, it just doesn't make sense that it doesn't have the "impala" tag since it's a question just about that exact thing ! When I stumbled upon this question, none of the current tags reflect what the question was about. And as people said on meta, even closed questions should be easily searchable, which is not the case currently. But if the "New Tag Deletionist Cabal" refuses this tag, I'll abide.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy, the problem is that you stated in your edit note that "multiple questions on the topic already" -- then go find them and tag *them* instead.  Creating a new tag *just* for a closed question (that can not be salvaged) is insanity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably best to try and understand what each of these projects is individually. Most people don't need to use all of them.

HDFS: A distributed file system. It takes files, splits them up into blocks, and distributes these across a cluster. It replicates these blocks for redundancy and to keep the data close to where it might get analyzed in a job. It is often used directly to store unstructured data like logs and text.

MapReduce: A programming model and set of software tools for running parallel programs. "YARN" is a more recent idea that allows other programs to be executed across a Hadoop cluster, and the most recent versions of "MapReduce" or programs that run on this "YARN" cluster. There's a lot to explain here and you're probably basically familiar with it, so I'll move on...

HBase: A non-relational database that persists it's data to HDFS and is structured like Google's BigTable. It stores data in memory to provide near-real-time lookups and live service. It is often used instead of using HDFS directly for structured data, like a web site's users.

Flume: A tool for managing data (such as logs) as it is constantly fed into HDFS.

Oozie: A tool for building more complicated jobs out of sequences of MapReduce jobs.

Sqoop: A tool for importing / exporting data between HDFS and relational databases. It does this by compiling the job to perform into a MapReduce job.

Zookeeper: A "cluster-coordination service". I think of this as an hierarchical file system (for relatively small chunks of data) that lets you build cluster-wide mutexes, get notifications of changes, etc. It can be hard to explain, but it basically gives you a set of operations you can use to build fairly complicated coordination mechanisms in your cluster. HBase uses Zookeeper for this purpose.

Hive: A tool that translates SQL-like queries into MapReduce jobs. (Pig is a similar idea - it's a programming language that compiles into MapReduce jobs).

Hue: "Hue User Experience" - it's a browser based UI for using Hadoop tools like Hue. It's also made by Cloudera, but is different from tools like Cloudera Manager that are intended for administering a cluster, rather than using the services themselves.

Bigtop: Packages many components of the hadoop ecosystem and similar tools in various ways (e.g. DEBs and RPMs for Linux, Puppet code for deploying Hadoop, even a Live CD). It's actually intended to start simplifying and standardizing the "integration" you refer to.

Pig: A similar idea to Hive - a programming language that compiles into MapReduce jobs.

Impala: A tool for exploring data in Hadoop with SQL-like queries. In exchange for supporting a simpler query language than Hive and not using MapReduce (which is intended for large batch jobs), it's supposed to make queries fast enough to explore large data sets interactively.